# How to separate values with Parse name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a value  (500 , 850 , 65.5) as GivenUnitPrice and I want to separate these by making separate columns by `PARSENAME`

I have tried like this

```
PARSENAME(GivenUnitPrice, 3) as DB,
        PARSENAME(GivenUnitPrice, 2) as Owner,
        PARSENAME(GivenUnitPrice, 1) as Object
```

and the result is

```
DB   |     Owner      |      Object
NULL | 500 , 850 , 65 |       5
```

Comment: `PARSENAME` is intended to be used against _object_ names (e.g. fully qualified table names), and it operates by splitting a _single_ string (no whitespace) on the dot separators.  Your input is not suitable for `PARSENAME`.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to seperate the characters by commas but `Parsename()` function splits by dot character( *e.g. decimal number 65.5 is also splitted as if seperate integers* ), so yields wrong results for your case. It's better to use `replace()`,`substring()` and `charindex()` together as :

```
with t as
(
select replace(replace('500 , 850 , 65.5',')',''),'(','') as GivenUnitPrice 
), t2 as
(
 select substring(GivenUnitPrice,1,charindex(',',GivenUnitPrice)-1) as db,
        substring(GivenUnitPrice,charindex(',',GivenUnitPrice)+1,len(GivenUnitPrice)) as owner_object       
   from t
)    
select db,
       substring(owner_object,1,charindex(',',owner_object)-1) as owner,
       substring(owner_object,charindex(',',owner_object)+1,len(owner_object)) as object
  from t2;

 db  owner  object
 500  850    65.5
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/ROS28832)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @GivenUnitPrice VARCHAR(100)= '500 , 850 , 65.5' 

 SELECT PARSENAME(replacE(@GivenUnitPrice,',','.'),4)  as DB,PARSENAME(replacE(@GivenUnitPrice,',','.'),3)  as Owner,PARSENAME(replacE(@GivenUnitPrice,',','.'),2)+ '.'+PARSENAME(@GivenUnitPrice,1) AS OBJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
DECLARE @UnitPrice VARCHAR(100)

SET  @UnitPrice= '500 , 850 , 65.5' 

SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@UnitPrice,',','.'),4)  as DB,

PARSENAME(REPLACE(@UnitPrice,',','.'),3)  as Owner,

PARSENAME(REPLACE(@UnitPrice, ',', '.'), 2) AS OBJECT,

PARSENAME(REPLACE(@UnitPrice, '', '.'), 1) AS OBJECT
```

[image: OutPut]

Answer (score 0):

PARSENAME basically consider .(Dot) as a delimeter in the string. In your input string, there are only one .(Dot) available at the end and as a result you are getting values only at Owner and Object column. IF you want to use PARSENAME for this string, please replace commas with .(Dot) first and then apply PARSENAME as below-

```
DECLARE @ObjectName NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @ObjectName = '500 , 850 , 65.5';
SET @ObjectName = REPLACE(@ObjectName, ',', '.');

SELECT PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 4) AS Server, 
       PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 3) AS DB, 
       PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 2) AS Owner, 
       PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 1) AS Object;
```